# How can I lose 100 pounds?

Tags: diet

Is there a FREE 1200 to 1400 calorie diet plan that has regular food (like normal food you buy in a local store) with no Hummas or Lamb or soy beans, something like eggs bread beans and rice burgers fruits that kind of food nothing fansy. It there a step by step day by day for 21 days straight diet menu that I can just praint out buy the food at my local Walmart and just do the 21 day 1200 to 1400 calorie diet until I lose the 100 pounds

Answer (score 8):

Here's the deal, losing 100 pounds is a wholesale lifestyle change.  Now I personally paid for help, as I needed that accountability and someone to help troubleshoot when the weight wasn't coming off that week.  If you check out my profile, you'll find a bit about my story and where I went to lose weight.  However, while the principles I learned there will also work for you, the supplements that are part of that program don't apply to your wishes.

If you want to succeed, then you need to learn how to manipulate your pancreas.  That is the one thing that has been proven to work time and time again.  Essentially, low carb/high protein (in proportions) is the quickest way to safely lose weight.  Unfortunately you aren't going to find something so simple as what you are asking for.

If you are serious about losing weight (without exercise):

- Get someone to hold your feet to the fire.  Your willpower alone is too weak, and the very act of someone reviewing your food diary will help you say "no" to foods you would normally say yes to.
- Read nutrition labels, you will need to shop differently.
- Find out how much body fat you have (even a rough estimate will work).  This is what you will use to track progress.
- You need to eat 0.5g protein for every pound of lean mass you have.  Lean mass is how much you would weigh without the fat.  Whole protein sources here, like meat (chicken, lean beef, pork chop, fish [best source right there])
- You will need to eat 4 servings of *green* vegetables a day.  You want the carb count to be low.
- Choose how serious you are going to be: go in to ketosis or a slower route.  To go in to ketosis you can not have any more than 40g of carbs a day.  While you are losing weight you want to cut carbs as much as possible.
- Ketosis will be quicker, but the protein is that much more important.  In fact you may want to temporarily increase the amount of protein you are eating to protect your muscles and organs.  If you skimp on protein your body will convert the muscle mass and organs to blood sugar--and that will slow your metabolism down requiring even deeper calorie deficits to compensate.  Protein is a non-negotiable part of ketogenic diets.

Get used to serving sizes like this:

- 2 whole eggs at a meal
- 7oz seafood (fish, lobster, etc.)
- 5oz land meat (chicken, beef, lamb, etc.)

Get used to saying "Don't finish it in butter" when you go out.  Get used to saying no to carbs until you reach your goal weight.

I've answered why this works several times before.  If you go to my profile and look at the answers I've given, you'll understand a whole lot more.

Comment: +1 upvote for I like your clear enlightening explanation, thanks! I lost 37kg this past year, so that needs about 8kg more additional weight to answer this Question, not to mention I can't explain as good as yours unless I allocate much more time to put my diet **practice** into _words_. What I remember is I only use corn oil to eat fried food twice a week maximum, each serving only 1-2 tea spoon. Now I can add some of your recipe to my recipe to try. I just love varieties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief summary of a diet plan http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/04/06/how-to-lose-20-lbs-of-fat-in-30-days-without-doing-any-exercise/ it's not so much about restricting calories as it is upping your protein intake, and cutting out other various food types.  It's very simple and easy to follow, but it can get plain eating the same things over and over if you don't spice it up some.  Theres probably plenty of other posts about it with more detailed instructions if you google the slow carb diet.  Or if your interested you could get the book on amazon.  It's worked for me.